# Conservative configuration of the PS1 variable

Tags: ps1

I need to create global variable environment `PS1='[\u@\h ttyid:\l \d \t \W]\$ '`?
I used command

```
$ export PS1
$ PS1='[\u@\h ttyid:\l \d \t \W]\$ '
```

Is that correct?

After that A conservative configuration of the PS1 environment variable is required for subsequent startup of the operating system by creating a suitable configuration file using the text editor.

Comment: when i customised my bash prompt i just went into the .bashrc file and commented out the default prompt and placed my own underneath you could try that

Comment: When you say global, do you mean for all sessions for one user, or all users?